# Copy previous line to current line from text file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a file with lines, just like this:

```
A
B
C
```

I want to create a duplicate file in bash that contains each line merged with the copy of next line, like:

```
A;B
B;C
C;
```

Comment: Does your input file contain any `;` characters?

Comment: No, there is no ; in the input file.

Comment: paste -d';' file <(sed 1d file)
comment by @αғsнιη

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'prev{ print prev ";" $0 }
     { prev = $0 }
     END { if (NR) print prev ";" }'
```

which with your input, gives

```
A;B
B;C
C;
```

Answer (score 16):

Quick'n'dirty way (involves reading the file twice):

```
$ tail -n+2 file | paste -d';' file -
A;B
B;C
C;
```

Comment: It reads the file twice, but every block is read by `paste` shortly after `tail` so it will be in cache. Chances are it's going to be more efficient than `sed`/`awk` based solutions. One down side is it can't work on pipes.

Comment: alternatively `paste -d';' file <(sed 1d file)`

Answer (score 8):

```
$ sed 'x;G;s_\n_;_;1d;${p;x;s_$_;_;}' file
A;B
B;C
C;
```

What that `sed` expression is doing:

- `x`: save the incoming line in hold space, and retrieve the previous one
- `G`: append the new line (from hold space) to the old one
- `s_\n_;_`: replace line-break with a `;`.
- `1d`: if this is the first line, delete it (don't print it) and advance to next
- `${...;}`: if this is the last line...
- `p`: first print the joined pair
- `x`: retrieve the final line
- `s_$_;_`: append final `;`

Answer (score 6):

Somewhat simpler `sed` solution without hold space:

```
sed '$!N;y/\n/;/;p;y/;/\n/;D' file
```

- `$!N` to join next line (if any; the `$!` is not needed with GNU `sed` when not in POSIX mode)
- `y/\n/;/` replace the newline with `;`
- `p`rint the resulting line
- `y/;/\n/` to change back to newline, so with
- `D` you can get rid of the first line and continue with the next one

Comment: That last line is `C` instead of `C;` though on the OP's sample.

Comment: Ah, I thought there was an empty last line, but that's just a visual effect of SE formatting, it seems. So we need `$!y/;/\n/` if the trailing `;` is required.

Answer (score 5):

Same basic idea as the [awk solution given by Torin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/516738/22222):

```
$ perl -lne 'print "$last;$_" if defined $last; $last=$_;END{print "$last;" if $.}' file 
A;B
B;C
C;
```

Or, if you're into the whole brevity thing:

```
$ perl -lne'$.>1?print"$l;$_":1;$l=$_}{print"$l;"if$.' file 
A;B
B;C
C;
```

Answer (score 5):

**A Vim Solution**

One can issue this command (credit to Conspicuous Compiler for suggesting this):

```
vim "+%s/\n\(.\+\)*/;\1\n\1" sample.txt
```

---

Alternatively and probably more customarily, start Vim and open the file and issue the ex command:

```
:%s/\n\(.\+\)*/;\1\n\1
```

Explanation:

Substitute the pattern:

- the new line character,`\n`
- a character group,`\(.+\)`, which composes the entire next line. The quantifier which follows, `*`, just indicates that there can be zero or more matches

with the following:

- a semicolon
- followed by a reference to the character group, `\1`
- followed by the new line character, `\n`
- followed by a second reference to the character group, `\1`.

Before:
 [image]

After:

[image]

Comment: It may be helpful to some to have this is a one-liner.  e.g. `vim '+*ThisReallylongCommand*'`

Comment: You’re missing a + in the one-liner

Comment: Oau...such a nice solution for vim.

Comment: @  D. Ben Knoble - I fixed the ommission with, +. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
$ perl -lp -0777e 's/\n(?=(.*\n?))/;$1/g'  input.txt
```